# using WIF in ASP.NET Web API Service

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, wif

I am trying to do something like this:

1. I have a MVC4 Web App and a Web-API service (hosted on two separate roles in azure)
2. Another role runs CustomSTS1.
3. The MVC Web App trusts the CustomSTS1
4. Now the customer logs into the site he is redirected to the STS login page.
5. Once logged in, he is redirected back to the MVC Web Site.
6. From this web site, the customer performs actions, which in turn  invoke the web-API Service.

I have the SAML token in the web app, which I pass to the WebAPI service.

Now when I try to validate the SAML token at the Web API side, I get a

```
Message=ID1032: At least one 'audienceUri' must be specified in the SamlSecurityTokenRequirement when the AudienceUriMode is set to 'Always' or 'BearerKeyOnly'. Either add the valid URI values to the AudienceUris property of SamlSecurityTokenRequirement,  or turn off checking by specifying an AudienceUriMode of 'Never' on the SamlSecurityTokenRequirement.
```

This is without the Web API service trusting the CustomSTS1

Once I setup the trust, 
I am always given a HTTP 401: UNAUTHORIZED, whenever I try to make a HTTP Get request to the WEB API Service.

Now, My Question is, (I know that my current approach is definitely wrong)

1. How do I setup the Trust relationship with the CustomSTS1, such that the WebAPI service is able to do an ActAS on behalf of the user logged into the MVC site?

OR

1. Is this architecture wrong?
2. And is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: can you share webapi service config and web app config

Answer (score 1):

That approach is wrong conceptually. The MVC application should negotiate a new token for the Web API in the STS using ActAs. That's how it traditionally works for SOAP Services. However, Web APIs are moving away from SAML as it is a complex format that relies on different WS-* specs. OAuth 2.0 is becoming the standard in that area if you want to support SSO at that level.

Another approach is to establish an implicit trust between the MVC app and the Web API, so all the calls to the Web API from the MVC app are done through a more standard Http auth mechanism like Basic Auth using an specific set of credentials that only the MVC app knows. The info about the logged user in the MVC app is passed as additional information.

Regards,
Pablo.